# Configuration changes in system.js 0.19 to 0.20

Tags: systemjs

Hi the first thing I hit in migrating is the difference in the way "paths" work. I had a reference to

```
paths: { "myLib:*" : "path/to/mylib" }
```

and then in `map: { angular: "myLib:/angular/angular }`

But this seems to be gone. How can I do it now in the latest system.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to run your system.js 0.19 with warnings: true. Then it gives you good info.

'myLib/': 'path/to/myLib/'

It is much simpler now, you just end in a trailing slash on the path and use myLib like a folder in your map paths, no semi colon.